# Match a part of a string using regex

Tags: regex

I have a string and would like to match a part of it.

The string is Accept: `multipart/mixedPrivacy: nonePAI: <sip:4168755400@1.1.1.238>From: <sip:4168755400@1.1.1.238>;tag=5430960946837208_c1b08.2.3.1602135087396.0_1237422_3895152To: <sip:4168755400@1.1.1.238>`

I want to match PAI: `<sip:4168755400@`
the whitespace can be a word so i would like to use .* but if i used that it matches most of the string

The [example](https://regex101.com/r/FjAmf4/1) on that link is showing what i'm matching if i use the whitespace instead of .*

```
(PAI: <sip:)((?:\([2-9]\d{2}\)\ ?|[2-9]\d{2}(?:\-?|\ ?))[2-9]\d{2}[- ]?\d{4})@
```

The [example](https://regex101.com/r/S8bqxO/1) on that link is showing what i'm trying to achieve with .* but it should only match PAI: <sip:4168755400@

```
(PAI:.*<sip:)((?:\([2-9]\d{2}\)\ ?|[2-9]\d{2}(?:\-?|\ ?))[2-9]\d{2}[- ]?\d{4})@
```

I tried lookaround but failing.
Any idea?
thanks

Comment: Format your question appropriately.

Comment: Doesn't https://regex101.com/r/FjAmf4/1 (your first link) work?

Comment: If what you might have to match doesn't contain any `<`, use `[^<]*` instead of `.*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it does, OP is worried that there might be other words on the line after "PAI:"

Comment: And OP, ideally you should include an example of such input that your first regex would fail to match but answers to your question should match as well

Comment: If the space can also be a word, or perhaps multiple words and spaces, you can use `(PAI:[ \w]+<sip:)((?:\([2-9]\d{2}\) ?|[2-9]\d{2}[ -]?)[2-9]\d{2}[- ]?\d{4})@` See https://regex101.com/r/V10BMX/1 The pattern can be a bit shortened by removing superfluous escapes and using a character class to combine the space and hyphen using `[- ]`

Comment: the answer from The fourth bird is what i was looking for. thank you

Comment: if i only use this sort of layout 4168755400 without () or - can i use this (PAI:[ \w]+<sip:)([2-9]\d{2}[2-9]\d{2}\d{4})@ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matching the single space can be updated by using a character class matching either a space or a word character and repeat that 1 or more times to match at least a single occurrence.

Note that you don't have to escape the spaces, and in both occasions you can use an optional character class matching either a space or hyphen `[ -]?`

If you want the match only, you can omit the 2 capturing groups if you want to.

```
(PAI:[ \w]+<sip:)((?:\([2-9]\d{2}\) ?|[2-9]\d{2}[ -]?)[2-9]\d{2}[- ]?\d{4})@
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V10BMX/1)

Answer (score 2):

The regex should be like

```
PAI:.*?(<sip:.*?@)
```

Explanation:

- `PAI:.*?` find the word `PAI:` and after the word it can be anything `(.*)` but `?` is used to indicate that it should match as few as possible before it found the next expression.
- `(<sip:.*?@)` capturing group that we want the result.
- `<sip:.*?@` find `<sip:` and after the word it can be anything `.*?` before it found `@`.

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/A9v4tS/1)